# How do i handle streaming messages with Python gRPC

Tags: python, stream, grpc

I'm following this [Route_Guide sample](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.8.x/examples/python/route_guide/route_guide_client.py).

The sample in question fires off and reads messages without replying to a specific message. The latter is what i'm trying to achieve.

Here's what i have so far:

```
import grpc
...

channel = grpc.insecure_channel(conn_str)
try:
    grpc.channel_ready_future(channel).result(timeout=5)
except grpc.FutureTimeoutError:
    sys.exit('Error connecting to server')
else:
    stub = MyService_pb2_grpc.MyServiceStub(channel)
    print('Connected to gRPC server.')
    this_is_just_read_maybe(stub)


def this_is_just_read_maybe(stub):
    responses = stub.MyEventStream(stream())
    for response in responses:
        print(f'Received message: {response}')
        if response.something:
            # okay, now what? how do i send a message here?

def stream():
    yield my_start_stream_msg
    # this is fine, i receive this server-side
    # but i can't check for incoming messages here
```

I don't seem to have a `read()` or `write()` on the stub, everything seems to be implemented with iterators.

How do i send a message from `this_is_just_read_maybe(stub)`?
Is that even the right approach?

My Proto is a bidirectional stream:

```
service MyService {
  rpc MyEventStream (stream StreamingMessage) returns (stream StreamingMessage) {}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're trying to do is perfectly possible and will probably involve writing your own request [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) object that can be given responses as they arrive rather than using a simple generator as your request iterator. Perhaps something like

```
class MySmarterRequestIterator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self._responses_so_far = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def _next(self):
        # some logic that depends upon what responses have been seen
        # before returning the next request message
        return <your message value>

    def __next__(self):  # Python 3
        return self._next()

    def next(self):  # Python 2
        return self._next()

    def add_response(self, response):
        with self._lock:
            self._responses.append(response)
```

that you then use like

```
my_smarter_request_iterator = MySmarterRequestIterator()
responses = stub.MyEventStream(my_smarter_request_iterator)
for response in responses:
    my_smarter_request_iterator.add_response(response)
```

. There will probably be locking and blocking in your `_next` implementation to handle the situation of gRPC Python asking your object for the next request that it wants to send and your responding (in effect) "wait, hold on, I don't know what request I want to send until after I've seen how the next response turned out".

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, i'll try that out. Any particular reason Python gRPC doesn't expose `.send()` and `.recv()` primitives, like the Golang implementation does, and pretty much all the others do?

Comment: At the time the API was being designed it was viewed as a bit of an edge case for Python use cases, so we went with what's most common being what's most straightforward and what's less common being possible with just a little more work.

Comment: The thing is, how scalable is this solution when serving bidirectional connections to many clients with all these locks?

Answer (score 16):

Instead of writing a custom iterator, you can also use a blocking queue to implement send and receive like behaviour for client stub:

```py
import queue
...

send_queue = queue.SimpleQueue()  # or Queue if using Python before 3.7
my_event_stream = stub.MyEventStream(iter(send_queue.get, None))

# send
send_queue.put(StreamingMessage())

# receive
response = next(my_event_stream)  # type: StreamingMessage
```

This makes use of the sentinel form of [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), which converts a regular function into an iterator that stops when it reaches a sentinel value (in this case `None`).

Comment: If send_queue is a consumer, will the stub.MyEventStream keep iterating send_queue after send_queue reaches empty and then get values ?

Comment: it should be "put" instead of "push"